# java: How to make swap button between 2 spinners and get the text of a Spinner?

Tags: java, android

i have two spinners. I want to make a button that it swaps values between them. For example, if spinner 1 has "Cat" and spinner 2 has "Dog" the thing i want is to swap them, so they would be, spinner 1 has "Dog" and spinner 2 has "Cat". Second things, is how to get text of a spinner? I want it to use it in an If statement, for example: If spinner 1.text = "USD" then txt.setText("America").

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: i have tried this : ` spinner_to.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

```
            if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("EGP")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.egp);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("USD")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.usd);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("EUR")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.eur);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("QAR")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.qar);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("SAR")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.sar);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("GBP")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.gbp);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("KWD")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.kwd);
            }  else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("LBP")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.lbp);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("OMR")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.omr);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("AED")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.aed);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("YER")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.yer);
            }  else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("LYD")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.lyd);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("ILS")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.ils);
            } else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("JOD")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.jod);
            }else if (spinner_to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("INR")) {
                img_to.setImageResource(R.drawable.inr);
            }

        }
    });`
```

but it gives me this app is not responding when i open it..

Comment: post what you've tried ...code?

Comment: I have tried this, it works but it doesn't give me the exact text. s1.getSelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: It's best to edit your question, rather than adding text in comments.

Comment: check it, i edited it.

Comment: Never mind, it worked. Now what about the SWAP button?>.